# Where can I get information on working with Swift Process()?

Tags: swift, macos, process

Specifically I would like the **correct syntax** to run git clone via Swift and do assorted Darwin-layer work like running tar compression etc.

Where can I get some usage info of Process()?

Essentially, I want to do something like this:
Process().git clone...
Process().tar ....

I want to conveniently work with the Darwin layer to do rudimentary stuff.

It would be nice to do this synchronously, to continue processing after the unix layer has done its task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out more about `Process` from [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process) or you could look at the source code of the open source version on [GitHub](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/Process.swift).

I wrote a short example for how you could make some code in the syntax you're looking for from `Process`. You could make changes to how the function accepts arguments so that it accepts an array of strings instead of specific named arguments.

```swift
extension Process {

    private static let gitExecURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/git")

    func clone(repo: String, path: String) throws {
        executableURL = Process.gitExecURL
        arguments = ["clone", repo, path]
        try run()
    }

}

try! Process().clone(repo: "git@github.com:user/repo.git", path: "path/to/repo")
```

As far as I know there's no way to pass the arguments to the process other than as a string.

Comment: Apple's documentation is limited.  I suppose I have to go back to NSTask and work from there.

Comment: I want to do something like Process().git clone....
or, Process().tar ....

I don't know the syntax.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some code. If you're running from Xcode you will have to do like the above to get your code to run in the correct directory or pass the directory you want to clone into to git however, if you can control the directory where you execute this code, you can use the `run` type method documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process/2890108-run).

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer since you've decided to use it?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I did.