# Attempting to clone a git repository via Swift encounters a Protocol Violation

Tags: swift, git, macos, headless

Darwin-via-Swift Neophyte here.

This is the continuation of: [Intro to Process()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658963/where-can-i-get-information-on-working-with-swift-process/55659304?noredirect=1#comment98011356_55659304).

I'm trying to get my hand around the use of Swift as a means to automate Darwin-Level processes like cloning a git repository, tarring a folder, etc.

I was given a template to attempt to do a clone (via above link). 
I've created a test link; and
tried it out at the Darwin prompt.

So I know it works. 
But I'm getting the protocol error via my Swift script.

What's the remedy here?

Is there a particular protocol that I must use?

```
import Foundation

extension Process {

    private static let gitExecURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/git")

    public func clone(repo: String, path: String) throws {
        executableURL = Process.gitExecURL
        arguments = ["clone", repo, path]
        try run()
    }

}


let source = "git clone https://AmourineTech@bitbucket.org/AmourineTech/testbit.git"
let target = "/Users/Ric/workarea"

print("Hello, World!")

try! Process().clone(repo: source, path: target)

print("Done")
```

Console Output:

```
Hello, World!
Done
Cloning into '/Users/Ric/workarea'...
fatal: protocol 'git clone https' is not supported
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `source` must be an URL, not a `git clone` command:

```
let source = "https://AmourineTech@bitbucket.org/AmourineTech/testbit.git"
```